Finding the quantum canonical density matrix from the microcanonical one by tracing over the reservoir
If we have an isolated quantum system we can use the quantum microcanonical density matrix defined by
$$ \rho_{mic}=\sum_n \frac{p_n}{\Omega}|n\rangle\langle n|$$
where $|n\rangle$ are the stationary states of the hamiltonian $H|n\rangle=E_n |n\rangle$ and $p_n$ is one if $E_n\in [E, E+\delta E]$ (equal a priori probabilities), zero otherwise. The trace is $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho_{mic})=1/\Omega$, with $\Omega$ the total number of stationary states. 
If now we consider a thermal reservoir and a small system inside it, the total system is always isolated and so we can describe it with $\rho_{mic}$. For the small system we can use the canonical ensemble, and use a density matrix
$$\rho_{c}=\frac{1}{\mathcal{Z}_c}e^{-\beta H_{syst.}}$$
with $\mathcal{Z}_c=\mathrm{Tr}(e^{-\beta H_{syst.}})$ the canonical partition function and $H_{syst.}$ the hamiltonian of the system.
My question is how can we derive this $\rho_{c}$ by tracing over the reservoir, that is to say
$$\rho_c = \mathrm{Tr}_{res.}(\rho_{mic})?$$

Possible duplicate: Derive Density Matrix of Canonical Ensemble by Tracing out the Reservoir

https://chatgpt.com/share/672124b2-0c3c-8011-9fec-83b33ea1613f
